# Constructive proof of approximate Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem for $\Delta^n$ via Sperner's lemma

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, fixed-point-theorems, constructive-mathematics

Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem (**BFPT**) is not provable in [Bishop-style](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642649059) constructive mathematics (**BISH**). For quick orientation, **BISH** is obtained from classical mathematics by removing the Law of Excluded Middle (**LEM**) and replacing the full Axiom of Choice by the Axiom of Dependent Choice.

Standard classical proofs of **BFPT** either rely on **LEM** or the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, which is equivalent to the Limited Principle of Omniscience, a constructively inadmissible weakening of **LEM**. **BFPT** itself is equivalent to Weak König's Lemma in **BISH**, and thus to the Lesser Limited Principle of Omniscience, another constructively inadmissible weakening of **LEM**.

However, the following approximate version of **BFPT** is known to be provable in **BISH**.

Recall that $$\Delta^n=\bigg\{\textbf{x}=(x_0,...,x_n)\mid\sum_{i=0}^{n}x_i\leq1 \land \forall i: 0\leq x_i \leq 1 \bigg\}$$ and let $d$ be the Euclidian metric on $\Delta^n$.

**Approximate Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem**

> Let $f$ be a uniformly continuous function from $\Delta^n$ into
> itself. Then for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\textbf{x}\in\Delta^n$ such
> that $d(f(\textbf{x}),\textbf{x})<\varepsilon$.

The assumption of uniform continuity is essential since the classical Uniform Continuity Theorem is not provable in **BISH**. Here's my proof attempt:

The proof in **BISH** proceeds via Sperner's Lemma.

Consider a uniformly continuous function $f$ from $\Delta^n$ into itself. Fix $m,k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $2^{-k}+2^{-k-2}+2^{-k-3}<2^{-m}$ and $$d(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})<2^{-k}+2^{-k-2}\Longrightarrow d(f(\textbf{x}),f(\textbf{y}))<2^{-m}.$$

Consider a simplical subdivision $\mathcal{S}$ of $\Delta^n$ with grid size $2^{-k}$. Specify a labeling as follows. A vertex $x$ of a simplex in $\mathcal{S}$ gets assigned the label $i$ if, and only if, $f(\textbf{x})_i<x_i$ or $f(\textbf{x})_i<x_i+2^{-k-3}$. This is constructively well-defined by the Approximate Splitting Principle and constitutes a feasible labeling in the sense of Sperner's Lemma. Thus, $\mathcal{S}$ contains a subsimplex $S$ whose $n+1$ vertices are labeled with $0,1,...,n$. We must now show that for a vertex $\textbf{s}$ of $S$, $d(f(\textbf{s}),\textbf{s})<n(2^{-m+1})$ holds (cf. [Scarf, 1967](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2099173); [van Dalen, 2011](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397511002787?via%3Dihub)).

This is where I got stuck.

Denote the vertex of $S$ labeled by $j$ by $\textbf{s}^j$ and consider $\textbf{s}^1$. By the definition of the labeling, $f(\textbf{s}^1)_1<s^1_1+2^{-k-3}$ and for each $i\neq 1$, we have $f(\textbf{s}^i)_i<s^i_i+2^{-k-3}$. I just can't figure out how to infer from this and the uniform continuity of $f$ that $d(f(\textbf{s}^1),\textbf{s}^1)<n(2^{-m+1})$ must hold.

I'm sure the argument is fairly easy, but I just can't see it. A "visual" argument for $\Delta^2$ is in the paper by van Dalen referenced above. While it helps me see *that* the conclusion is true for $\Delta^1$ and $\Delta^2$, I am still unable to derive it formally, let alone generalize it to $\Delta^n$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

---

**Update**

In the meantime, I worked out the details of the proof myself. I'll post the full argument as an answer here soon.

Comment: Ludwig can I ask you a question. Are you sure the proof of Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem really requires Bolzano-Weierstrass? I am asking this question because I am not sure Bolzano-Weierstrass is really needed.Let's assume we can find a proof NOT using Bolzano-Weierstrass, would this satisfy your requirements about constructive proofs?

Comment: @Claus BFPT implies LLPO over BISH (in fact, they're equivalent in the presence of countable choice). LLPO is trivially true in CLASS (because it's a consequence of LEM), provably false in RUSS (where it's closely related to the Halting problem) and, therefore, independent of BISH. Hence, BFPT is independent of BISH. This also tells you that BWT is not strictly speaking necessary for BFPT, as BWT is constructively equivalent to LPO, which is stronger than LLPO. In the proof of BFPT via Sperner's Lemma BWT is needed to pass to the limit of a sequence of vertices of fully labeled subsimplices.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is LLPO? And I still have the feeling BWT is not required. I know that BWT is typically used in this proof, but I keep thinking you could do without. The trick to avoid BWT could be, I imagine, to use barycentric subdivision for the triangulation